# How to add ENTITYs when serialising?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

**Question**

Can I modify my POCO classes so that when serialised they contain the `ENTITY`s required?  After reading [this from W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#ENTITY) and [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281682/reference-to-undeclared-entity-exception-while-working-with-xml#842836) I realised my XML should contain the `DOCTYPE` as below, I just don't know how to insert it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE documentElement[<!ENTITY NZ "NZ"><!ENTITY AU "AU">]>
<ValuationTransaction xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://vx.valex.com.au/lixi/schema/1.3.5/ValuationTransaction.xsd" ProductionData="Yes">
    ... etc.
</ValuationTransaction>
```

My serialising code looks like this

```
public static string ToXmlString(this ValuationTransaction payloadPoco)
{
    var stringwriter = new StringWriter();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(payloadPoco.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, payloadPoco);
    return stringwriter.ToString();
}
```

**Background**

I'm serialising my root class to a string using an `XmlSerializer` and a `StringWriter`, then validating the XML string using an XmlValidator from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751511/validating-an-xml-against-referenced-xsd-in-c-sharp).  While validating the XML the validator says...

> Reference to an undeclared entity, 'NZ'. at line 37 position 24

... which refers to the `ISO3166` attribute of this element

```
<Country ISO3166="NZ">NEW ZEALAND</Country>
```

... the definition for which is:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "ENTITY")]
public string ISO3166
{
    get { return this.iSO3166Field; }
    set { this.iSO3166Field = value; }
}
```

The range of values is limited for my purposes to `NZ` and `AU`.  I *can* add the `DOCTYPE` like this, though obviously I'd rather find a better way:

```
var entitiesDtd = @"<!DOCTYPE documentElement[<!ENTITY NZ ""NZ""><!ENTITY AU ""AU"">]>" + Environment.NewLine;
xmlString = xmlString.Insert(xmlString.IndexOf("<ValuationTransaction"), entitiesDtd);
```

The definition for the XML root class (generated by `xsd.exe` and manually tweaked to add `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`) is

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class ValuationTransaction
{
    [XmlAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "https://vx.valex.com.au/lixi/schema/1.3.5/ValuationTransaction.xsd";
    ... etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my serialisation a little so that it included an `XmlWriter` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml#4123648).

```
XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ValuationTransaction));
var subReq = payloadPoco;
var xml = "";

using (var sww = new StringWriter())
{
    var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    writerSettings.Indent = true;

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww, writerSettings))
    {
        writer.WriteDocType("documentElement", null, null, "<!ENTITY AU \"Australia\"><!ENTITY NZ \"New Zealand\">");
        xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, subReq);
        xml = sww.ToString(); // Your XML
        return xml;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add settings

```
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww, settings);
```

Comment: Thanks - I was just finding that out as you wrote.  Not sure if by itself that works as an answer to the question though.

Comment: You are missing a namespace NZ.  Should have xmlns:NZ some place in the xml.

Comment: The validator seems happy without a namespace on the entity, and the example on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writedoctype(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have one. Could you show your reasoning why a namespace might be required?

Comment: Does it work if you remove : [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "ENTITY")]