# XmlDocument.LoadXml() and entities

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Using `XmlDocument.LoadXml()`, how can I load a string with `&` or `<` in it?

For instance, the following string causes an error:

`<choice id="A1"> sample < text</choice>`

Do I need to use a Resolver somehow? Can XmlDocument even handle things like this?

Comment: What error you get? Compilation error or runtime error? Post the details of the error.

Comment: Well, that's not valid XML, so XmlDocument won't load it. It should be `<choice id="A1"> sample &lt; text</choice>`. Where is the XML coming from?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It was a run-time error due to the data -- "Illegal character".

Comment: @stuartd You're right: I was letting the XML supplier perform an "entity expand" on the string. When I changed that, it loads and displays fine. Thanks!

Comment: @stuartd Now no other entities work, only "&" and "<" work. The run-time error is "Reference to undeclared entity 'dagger'" (e.g.). Ampersand and Less Than seem to be special and require unique treatment. How do I reference entities; is this where a Resolver comes into play?

Comment: See wiki to handle special characters : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: *How do I reference entities; is this where a Resolver comes into play?* -- can you provide a sample of XML that cannot be parsed?

Comment: @dbc In this example, "&para;" can't be resolved: <choice goto-fvid="1" goto-step-id="3-2-21.t1.s1">choice &para;&amp;&lt; 1</choice>

Comment: Well that's also malformed XML, upload it to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will see **Errors in the XML document: The entity "para" was referenced, but not declared.**  But `&para` is predefined in HTML, are you sure you shouldn't be parsing it as HTML as suggested in [Reference to undeclared entity exception while working with XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281703) instead?

Comment: @dbc I'm definitely using XML versus HTML (although obviously I'm new at it). Also, this is a string fragment that I want to load into an XmlDocument. I've learned there is an entity file available to the system, but my attempt to leverage it via XmlUrlResolver.ResolverUri() was unsuccessful; I'm still getting "Reference to undeclared entity". How do I reference these entities -- either W3C's or something on the local system?

Comment: @dbc Actually it did work -- it looks like using an XmlUrlResolver is the way to go. Thanks for your input!